# How to set up callback function?

Tags: ios, callback, ios8, xcode6

i have been stuck on this for a while. So in my app i will have buttons that plays sounds. When the user clicks the button(button1.png) i want to change to image to (button2.png), then when the sound has finished playing i want to change the picture pic to the original image. I think a callback would be best to set this up but im having trouble. Help would be Appreciated.

Here is my code

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
// change setContentSize When making scroll view Bigger and adding more items
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];  

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - CallBackMethods









#pragma mark - SystemSoundIDs
SystemSoundID sound1;







#pragma mark - Sound Methods
-(void)playSound1
{
 NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                  pathForResource:@"Sound1" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)url, &sound1);


static void (^callBAck)(SystemSoundID ssID, void *something);

callBAck = ^(SystemSoundID ssID, void *something){
    [button1 setImage:@"WhiteButton.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
};

 AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(sound1,
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL,
                                      callback,
                                      NULL);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound1);
}
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"Hello");
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonPressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self playSound1];    
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

`AudioToolbox` is a *C* framework (note the *C* style function call). 
So the callback you pass into it must be [*C function pointer*](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html).

Looking at the [`AudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/AudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc) type that you need to pass in as the 4th argument of `AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion` for the call back:

`typedef void (*AudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc) ( SystemSoundID ssID, void *clientData );`

It tells you that you need to declare a *C function* that accepts two parameters and returns void as the callback handler and pass it into `AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion`.

```
// Declare this anywhere in the source file.
// I would put this before @implement of the class.
void audioCompletionHandler(SystemSoundID ssID, void *clientData) {
    NSLog(@"Complete");
}

...

- (void)playSound {
    ...
    // To pass the function pointer, add & before the function name.
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(soundID, NULL, NULL, &audioCompletionHandler, NULL);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound);
}
```